# Excel formula for extracting a string not found in a list that is in a cell with a string of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets like in this example:

Worksheet 1

```
                A
```

1. 1| Type what sports do you like to play?
2. 2| basketball, football, soccer
3. 3| basketball, football, soccer, softball
4. 4| football, soccer, tennis

Worksheet 2

```
            A
```

2. 1| List of sports to choose from:
3. 2| basketball
4. 3| football
5. 4| soccer
6. 5| other

I need a formula that will tell me what the students wrote in for the other option like softball and tennis in my example.

Comment: This is probably going to require vba.

Comment: Do you know where I can find code to do that? I m not very familiar with vba, but have used it a couple of times

Comment: You will need to create it, you will need to load the current list into a collection or dictionary then split the student inputs on the `,` and try to load each of those into the dictionary or collection ignoring the errors when the duplicates fail to load.  Google each of the steps I have described and you will get a plethora of information.  When you have code that just will not work come back with said code and ask a specific question about that specific error.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show where the code is site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In worksheet 1, assuming your returned answers start in A2, you could use this formula, and drag down for each answer:

```
=IF(OR(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),100)," ","")="basketball",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),100)," ","")="football",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),100)," ","")="soccer"),"",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),100)," ",""))
```

This will return the last sport listed after the comma that is not basketball, football, or soccer, otherwise it returns blank.

[image]

Comment: This will be limited compared to what you can do with VBA, but may fill the needs in this circumstance.

Comment: Great! If this answers your question, would you please check the box marking it as an answer?